# karma-coverage includes node_modules

Tags: karma-jasmine, karma-coverage, karma-webpack

I have a karma config which for my unit test and code-cov. My project dir looks like below

```
RootFOlder
-karma.config.js
-webpack.test.config.js
-src/
--test.ts
--components
---ButonComponent
----Buttoncomponent.spec.ts
```

And my karma.config is below

```
// Karma configuration

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'src/test.ts',
      'src/components/**/*.component.ts',
    ],

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [
      'node_modules',
      './src/tsconfig.spec.json'
    ],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require("karma-coverage"),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-webpack'),
      require('karma-sourcemap-loader'),
      require('ts-loader')
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      'src/components/**/*.ts': ['coverage'],
      'src/components/**/*.component.ts': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
      'src/test.ts': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],

    },

    webpack: require('./webpack.test.config'),

    coverageReporter: {
      reporters: [
        { type: 'text', subdir: 'text' },
        { type: 'html', subdir: 'report-html' },
      ]
    },

    ...
    ...
  });
}
```

And my webpack.
    module.exports = {
      devtool: 'inline-source-map',
      mode: 'development',
      target: 'node',
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
      },

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['ts-loader', 'angular-router-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
      }
     ....
     ....

    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'test')
    }),
    // Removes warnings regarding Critical dependency
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)f?esm5/, path.join(__dirname, './src')
    )
  ],
  node: {
    console: false,
    global: true,
    process: true,
    Buffer: false,
    setImmediate: false
  }
}
```

The problem is after i run my test, my coverage covers the bundled node_modules. The file coverage endup being hude running in MBytes and my coverage low. Pls how do i exclude the node_modules from my coverage? Any help is appreciated .

Comment: hi.. did the answer help?

Answer (score 1):

By default you shouldn't even need to mention `node_modules` in the `exclude` path. Try removing it and see if the coverage is corrected?

If not,

try adding this to the `preprocessors`:

```
'!node_modules/**/*.*': ['coverage']
```